# Toll API Call is showing resident rate instead of actual rate for tolls

Tags: here-api

I am trying to get the tolls for a specific route. The API is returning $3.40 as the tollcost which is the Staten Island resident cost and not the actual cost $12.24. Wondering if there is a way to get it to show the actual rates and not the resident rates.

Api call:

```
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={API_KEY}&mode=car&waypoint0=40.65523%2C-73.95024&waypoint1=40.56042%2C-74.10192&alternatives=2&units=imperial&tollVehicleType=car&return=polyline%2Cactions%2Cinstructions%2Csummary%2CtravelSummary%2CturnByTurnActions%2Celevation%2CrouteHandle
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **&rollpus=none** to see the details:

```
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={API_KEY}&mode=car&waypoint0=40.65523%2C-73.95024&waypoint1=40.56042%2C-74.10192&alternatives=2&units=imperial&tollVehicleType=car&return=polyline%2Cactions%2Cinstructions%2Csummary%2CtravelSummary%2CturnByTurnActions%2Celevation%2CrouteHandle&rollpus=none
```

Comment: That did not help. I am still getting $3.40 for toll cost.